# They are all linked!

Tags: visual, grid-deduction, word-search, pencil-and-paper-games

Seems like this month's [topic](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7388/78877) is not getting enough attention. Here is a simple puzzle to revive the challenge.

---

This 'mess' is hiding some words/phrases. Find them all.

[image: puzzle]

.. and, what do they all represent?

#### Some tips:

(Helpful)

> One of them is an anagram, others are not!

(Maybe helpful)

> There are different types of characters. Focus on only one at a time.

(Least helpful)

> Everything is relevant.

*And don't forget the tags!*

Comment: This [penpa+ link](https://tinyurl.com/2gp5sgqq) would be helpful for someone. P.S. I feel like this is silly, like my first puzzle, yet posted :P

Comment: Very nice for a first puzzle!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, the solved

> Slitherlink:[image]
>  The loop can be divided into six 3-by-3 subregions: each of these can be read as a letter and reading them in order yields **FENCES**.

Blue letters

> are arranged in two groups. The upper one spells **TAKEGAKI** and the lower one spells out **SURIZA**.

Red letters

> are arranged in two groups. The ones off the Slitherlink spell **OUROBOROS** and the ones on the Slitherlink spell out **DOTTY DILEMMA** (starting at the top left and reading clockwise).

Green letters

> all lie on the Slitherlink and spell **loop the loop**, when read the same way as the red letters.

Dotted regions

> can have the parts lying inside the loop shaded in. The resulting shapes can be rearranged to spell **LOOPY**.

What do these seven things have in common?

> They're all names for Slitherlink!

Comment: Fast solve! +1 and checkmark coming soon. A minor suggestion: if you can hide the fact in first sentence, it will be better (for those who want to try the puzzle themselves ;-) P.S: Just noticed, you are missing one word. : )

Comment: ...you sly dog...